# How to declare an array or a list in a Python @dataclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses, python-typing, type-hinting

How can I declare an array (or at least list) in `@dataclass`? A something like below:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Test():
    my_array: Array[ChildType]
```

Comment: `my_array: list`? Or `List[...]` if you want to specify the element type. But you'll have to import those things from the right places - `dataclass` isn't in `abc`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is no `Array` datatype, but you can specify the type of `my_array` to be `typing.List`:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List

@dataclass
class Test:
    my_array: List[ChildType]
```

And from Python 3.9 onwards, you can conveniently just use `list`:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Test:
    my_array: list[ChildType]
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I've updated question. I thought it has primary type

Comment: @Шах Edited my answer to also remove the useless `ABC` stuff.